Script for reading pdfs from NSE weblinks in a loop
I have a 1-column dataframe (python). Each row in the column contains a weblink. Each weblink leads to a pdf. For example: I have a column named 'Col1' which has three rows - each with a weblink from National Stock Exchange website
https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/corporate/GOCLCORP_27032024171815_UpdatesonKukatpallyLand27032024.pdf
https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/corporate/BLUEDART_27032024172244_PRESSRELEASE_240327_171841.pdf
https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/corporate/SOBHA_27032024173028_LettertoshareholdersupdationofKYC.pdf
How do I read the pdfs within these links directly into the dataframe, maybe into a new column?
!pip install requests
!pip install PyPDF2
!pip install beautifulsoup4

import requests
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def extract_text_from_pdf(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    with open('temp.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
    pdf = PdfFileReader('temp.pdf')
    text = ''
    for page_num in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
        page = pdf.getPage(page_num)
        text += page.extract_text()
    return text

